# How do I use the HTML download link to automatically save, open, and view the file in a specific folder?

Tags: html, file, url, download, auto

How do I generate an HTML PDF DOWNLOAD LINK? How do I get the PDF file automatically saved, opened, and view in a folder when I enter the HTML download link?

How do I generate an HTML pdf download link? And when I visit the link, that is, when I enter the download link, how can I ensure that the pdf file is automatically saved directly in a folder such as C:/Users/' on my computer? How do I get it saved, opened, and viewed? How do I get the file to be automatically saved, opened, and displayed in any folder I specify when I click on the download link?

How can I use HTML for this? And how do I generate that html download link?

Comment: To create a download link use `<a>` tag. To specify where downloads goes, that is dependent on what browser you are using and it's specific settings. Specifying the download location in the HTML is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a link download the linked resource (using `download` attribute), but that's all you can do. However, you can't specify the place to store the downloaded pdf, and you can't force if it will be opened after the download, for good reasons: these are things that will be decided by the user or the browser defaults.